# NPOI Excel number format not showing in Excel sheet in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, npoi

I am trying to create double and number format cells in excel using NPOI library. I used code like

```
Dim cell As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(j)
cell.SetCellValue(Double.Parse(dr(col).ToString))
```

In excel numbers are aligning right but when I check format it is showing in "General"

[image]

then I changed my code to like below

```
 Dim cell As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(j)
 cell.SetCellValue(Double.Parse(dr(col).ToString))
 Dim cellStyle As HSSFCellStyle = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle
 cellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("#,#0.0")
 cell.CellStyle = cellStyle
```

Then While opening file it is giving error and also taking so long  to open. But Excel format showing in "Number"

error showing is like below.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using NPOI 1.6 or greater?

Comment: 1.2.3 is the latest version, as far as I can tell:  http://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/49524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213904), are you creating a cellStyle object for each cell? If so don't. Try creating just a couple of styles before creating your cells and then apply these pre-defined styles to the cells you create.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the too many different cell styles declare all styles outside of any loop you may be running.

I'm presumeing you 'j' would be the enumerator so i'll drop what you had in a corrected format for you.

```
Dim cellStyle As HSSFCellStyle = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle
cellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("#,#0.0")

For col = 0 To ColoumCounter
  For j = 0 To Counter
    Dim cell As HSSFCell = row.CreateCell(j)
    cell.SetCellValue(Double.Parse(dr(col).ToString))
    cell.CellStyle = cellStyle
  Next
Next
```

This should work a bit better, by limiting the number of "New" styles.

Answer (score 0):

Hare is a simple way to create double format  in Excel Document **USING NPOI**.

```
//make NUMERIC Format in Excel Document // Author: Akavrelishvili
  var eRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex); //create new Row , rowIndex - it's integer, like : 1,2,3
  eRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(row["ProvidName"].ToString()); //create cell and set string value

  double Amount = Convert.ToDouble(row["Amount"].ToString()); //convert string to double
  eRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(Amount); // create cell and set double value.
```

This is working version, I have used it a lots of projects.

Very Hard is to insert DateTime format in Excel, There no good example in Internet and I think it helps people to do it right way.
I show you code example:

```
     //make Date Time Format in Excel Document // Author: Akavrelishvili
```

var eRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex); //create new Row // rowIndex - it's integer, like : 1,2,3

```
 ICellStyle cellDateStyle = workBook.CreateCellStyle(); //create custom style
 cellDateStyle.DataFormat = workBook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); //set day time Format

 eRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"])); //set DateTime value to cell
                    eRow.GetCell(6).CellStyle = cellDateStyle; // Restyle cell using "cellDateStyle"


I hope it helps
```

Comment: workBook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat();   is indeed the correct way to do it, haven't had any luck with GetBuiltinFormat()

Comment: I had finished solution, which uses this way to make correct DateTime Format and at this moment solution works without problem. I think this is a best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style then but this style for the column

```
 ICellStyle _TextCellStyle = wb1.CreateCellStyle();

 _TextCellStyle.DataFormat = wb1.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("@");
 sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(2, _TextCellStyle);
```